# jquery flot{mode : time} not giving time correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I am getting the current timestamp. But when I use

```
 vat time= (resp.timestamp * 1000);
 data.push([time,value]);
 $.plot($(".memory"),[data],{xaxis: {mode: "time"}});
```

The resp.timestamp is the current timestamp.
I am getting time in x axis in GMT, where as my local timezone is IST. How can I get the local time?
i.e. If the application is running in India it should show IST time, if running in Australia the AEST time.

**TRY1-**

```
 vat time= (resp.timestamp * 1000);
 data.push([time,value]);
 $.plot($(".memory"),[data],{xaxis: {mode: "time", timezone: "browser"}});
```

**TRY2-**

```
 vat time= (resp.timestamp * 1000);
 data.push([time,value]);
 $.plot($(".memory"),[data],{xaxis: {mode: "time", timezone: "offset"}});
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I copied jqquery.flot.time.js from github and pasted it in my local.

```
  vat time= (resp.timestamp * 1000);
  data.push([time,value]);
  $.plot($(".memory"),[data],{xaxis: {mode: "time"}});
```

And used the same mode: "time".